# Stored procedure order of execution/race

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a master stored procedure that runs other stored procedures, do those stored procedures complete execution in the order they were listed?

Ex: p_master

```
exec p_sp1
exec p_sp2
exec p_sp3
```

Will `p_sp1` complete execution before `p_sp2` executes, and will `p_sp2` complete execution before `p_sp3` executes?

If not, is it possible to force this to behave this way?

Comment: Yes -T-SQL  code operates sequentially? How else might it work?

Comment: Yes. SQL Server can run things in parallel , but that's inside a single statement - multiple statements would run sequentially. 

Moreover, if a statement fires a trigger, that trigger would execute before the next statement will start to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**

As an aside, **if you execute the stored procedures individually (i.e. not inside a master stored procedure)**, you should execute them like this:

```
exec p_sp1
Go

exec p_sp2
Go

exec p_sp3
Go
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: There is no general reason to force the execution of those stored procedure into separate batches when run individually.